# Dapper and Downward Integer Conversion

Tags: sqlite, dapper, system.data.sqlite

I am checking out v1.25 of Dapper with Sqlite via System.Data.Sqlite. If I run this query:

```
var rowCount = dbc.Query<int>("SELECT COUNT(*) AS RowCount FROM Data").Single();
```

I get the following error: `System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid`

This is because Sqlite returns the above value as an Int64, which I can verify with the following code. This will throw "Int64":

```
var row = dbc.Query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS RowCount FROM Data").Single();
Type t = row.RowCount.GetType();
throw new System.Exception(t.FullName);
```

Now, the following code will actually handle the downward conversion from Int64 to Int32:

```
public class QuerySummary
{
    public int RecordCount { get; set; }
}
var qs = dbc.Query<QuerySummary>("SELECT COUNT(*) AS RecordCount FROM Data").Single();
rowCount = qs.RecordCount;
throw new System.Exception(rowCount.ToString());
```

When I throw this exception, it gives me the actual row count, indicating that Dapper handled the conversion for me.

My question is, why is it that `dbc.Query<int>` does not handle the downward conversion in a similar way to `dbc.Query<QuerySummary>`? Is this intended behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that is not intentional. I've committed and pushed changes to github which make the following pass (it fails on 1.25); it should appear on NuGet at some point soon too:

```
    // http://stackoverflow.com/q/23696254/23354
    public void DownwardIntegerConversion()
    {
        const string sql = "select cast(42 as bigint) as Value";
        int i = connection.Query<HasInt32>(sql).Single().Value;
        Assert.IsEqualTo(42, i);

        i = connection.Query<int>(sql).Single();
        Assert.IsEqualTo(42, i);
    }
```

Comment: Marc, many thanks for addressing this so quickly. I checked NuGet but it doesn't look like it is available yet. I'll grab it off of Github later today if I get some time to test it out. Also, I'm happy to report that an issue I had converting nullable Int64 to Int32 that existed in 1.13 is gone in 1.25. Great stuff.

Comment: Just a quick report back, I downloaded the most recent build from Github and tested it out in a couple of scenarios I have been working with. It worked perfectly, no more exceptions. Thanks again.